# React flip card

Tags: reactjs

I have a little problem, i have a flip card and my card it doesn't "close". In "timer" function my card flip to show the front , then after 3 sec. it must  flip again and "close" (show the back of the card), but i don't know why my card doesn't flip again after 3 sec..

```
const [isFlipped, setisFlipped] = useState(false);
 const [isFlippedSecond, setIsFlippedSecond] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('first');
        setisFlipped(!isFlipped);
    }, 1000);

    const secondtimer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('second');
        setisFlipped(!isFlipped);
        setIsFlippedSecond(!isFlippedSecond);
  }, 3000);
  }, [isFlippedSecond]);

    <div className='FirstCards '>
            <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={isFlipped} flipDirection='vertical'>
                <div className=' location-front-item  frontCard'>
                  

                    <div className='FirstCardsFrontText'>
                        You don't feel any improvement?
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {' '}
                        이거 이해할 수 있으면 한국어 잘 할 수 있은가 봐요
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
   
                <div className=' location-back-item backCard'>
                    <div>
                        Don't worry, it's something normal that came when
                        you start to learn something new, give yourself
                        time, even a caterpillar need time until it change
                        into a butterfly and start to fly
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ReactCardFlip>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `isFlippedSecond` here (unless you use it for something else), use [] as dependency array to fire the timers once, like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("first");
      setisFlipped(!isFlipped);
    }, 1000);

    const secondtimer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("second");
      setisFlipped(!isFlipped);
    }, 3000);

    return () => { //Should clear the timers in useEffect
      clearInterval(timer);
      clearInterval(secondtimer);
    };
  }, []);
```

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-water-xn5ki?file=/src/App.js:150-499